# tau dash in an integral equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, algebra-precalculus

I am looking at an equation which looks like so:

$some_x = \int_{0}^{t} G(\tau - \tau')\dot{\textbf{e}}~dt'$

Unfortunately, the literature I am looking at does not have a description for $\tau'$ and I am wondering what this variable could be. Does $ \tau' = d\tau/dt$?

..I am unsure how one would proceed to compute:

$G(\tau - \tau')$

Sorry if this is a dumb question - new to math :)

Comment: Don't forget to wrap your expressions in dollar signs. `$G(\tau - \tau')$` will display as $G(\tau - \tau')$

Comment: @AdamFrancey: thanks man - I did not know that!

Comment: Can you give a bit more context?  What's the literature you're looking at?

Comment: @BrianTung: It is the first equation here:http://129.97.46.200:2080/v6.14/books/stm/ch04s08ath128.html I'd also love to know how the first equation can be written as a summation.

Comment: It's just an integration variable. So, the same thing as $\tau$, but running across the integration domain while $\tau$ is fixed.

Comment: @orion: I do not understand what you mean running across the int. domain while $\tau$ is fixed. Can you maybe write it as a summation and maybe it will be easier for me to understand? :(( So for example if I say $\tau$=$t$ (which is my case), how will this work? it would be (t-t') which is confusing to me since the integration has limits 0-->t